# select_related with reverse foreign keys

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset, django-1.5, django-managers

I have two Models in Django.  The first has the hierarchy of what job functions (positions) report to which other positions, and the second is people and what job function they hold.

```
class PositionHierarchy(model.Model):
    pcn = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    level = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    report_to = models.ForeignKey('PositionHierachy', null=True)


class Person(model.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    ...
    position = models.ForeignKey(PositionHierarchy)
```

When I have a Person record and I want to find the person's manager, I have to do

```
manager = person.position.report_to.person_set.all()[0]
# Can't use .first() because we haven't upgraded to 1.6 yet
```

If I'm getting people with a `QuerySet`, I can join (and avoid a second trip to the database) with position and report_to using `Person.objects.select_related('position', 'position__reports_to').filter(...)`, but is there any way to avoid making another trip to the database to get the person_set? I tried adding `'position__reports_to__person_set'` or just `position__reports_to__person` to the `select_related`, but that doesn't seem to change the query. Is this what `prefetch_related` is for?

I'd like to make a custom manager so that when I do a query to get Person records, I also get their PositionHeirarchy and their manager's Person record without more round trips to the database. This is what I have so far:

```
class PersonWithManagerManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        qs = super(PersonWithManagerManager, self).get_query_set()
        return qs.select_related(
            'position',
            'position__reports_to',
        ).prefetch_related(
        )
```

Comment: probably a typo, but it should be `get_queryset()`, not `get_query_set`.

Comment: @Paolo it was `get_query_set` in Django 1.5.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Yes, that is what `prefetch_related()` is for. It will require an additional query, but the idea is that it will get all of the related information at once, instead of once per `Person`.

In your case:

```
qs.select_related('position__report_to')
  .prefetch_related('position__report_to__person_set')
```

should require two queries, regardless of the number of `Persons` in the original query set.

Compare this example from the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related):

```
>>> Restaurant.objects.select_related('best_pizza')
                      .prefetch_related('best_pizza__toppings')
```