# how to get all fields of related model in django instead of only id

Tags: django

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class SeekerRegister(models.Model):
    seeker_name       = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    seeker_email      = models.CharField(max_length=32)

class Social(models.Model):
    social_links      = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    user              = models.ForeignKey(access_models.SeekerRegister,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='social',null=True,blank=True)
```

my query:

```
    >>>obj=list(SeekerRegister.objects.values('social'))
    >>>[{'social': 1}, {'social': 2}, {'social': 3}]
```

expecting:

```
    [{'social_links': 'facebook.com','user':1,'seeker_name':'a'}, {'social_links': 'twitter.com','user':2,'seeker_name':'b'}, {'social_links': 'linkedin.com','user':3,'seeker_name':'c'}]
```

when i am writing the above query i am getting only id of social model.
how can i get all fields both social_links and user instead.

please have a look into my code.

Comment: Instead of getting objects of SeekerRegister get objects of Social model. `Social.objects.values('social_links', 'user')`

Comment: i want data from both models by joining them . please have a look into my expecting result

Comment: Oh! you edited the question later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
SeekerRegister.objects.values('social__social_link', 'id', 'seeker_name')
```

where `social__social_link` is the `social_link` and `id` is `user`

Pleas check this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23121850/select-related-with-reverse-foreign-keys) for more details.